# Pull Refresh event on Sencha Architect

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

I have a list of items connected to a web server.

When the user pulls down the list it refreshes all items on the list.

I am using Sencha Architect, how can I do this?
I'm using an Ext.plugin.pullrefresher , but I can't find the way to bind the action of pulling with the function that updates the list.

```
plugins: [
                    {
                        pluginId: 'refArrivos',
                        type: 'pullrefresh'
                    }
                ]
```

How to add some code related to the event? Thanks

Comment: Sencha Architect is only good for putting together the elements of a project when you're first beginning to write an application.  Once your application begins to flesh out, the code generated in Architect breaks sometimes when you deploy to production.  I prefer Sublime Text 2, and code by hand.  You are asking to connect to a web server.  You will want to find a good server-side stack that's integrated with ExtJS.  I'd suggest learning ExtDirect (proprietary to Sencha), but you can find the server-side stacks (for ExtDirect) available for free on the web.  PHP, .NET, Java, Ruby, etc...

Comment: Regarding your question, I am not familiar with that plugin.  You could search for it on Sencha Fiddle.  https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/5ab